# Remove all list elements except the first in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I remove all the li elements except the first in PHP?

```
<div class="category">
   <ul class="products">
     <li>{nested child elements}</li>
     <li>{nested child elements}</li>
     <li>{nested child elements}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The code above is generated by another script via a function.

The result should be like this:

```
<div class="category">
    <ul class="products">
        <li>{nested child elements}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE: Sorry guys the "category" is a class not an ID.**

In repay to Yoshi, ul.products has siblings but I didn't include them in my post. Would that affect the query?

This is how my code looks like with Yoshi's code added:

```
class Myclass {
    function prin_html() {
        $content = get_code();
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadXml($content);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        foreach ($xpath->query('//li[position()>1]') as $liNode) {
            $liNode->parentNode->removeChild($liNode); 
        }

        echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);    
    }
}
```

It sill prints the non-filtered html code...

Comment: I would like it to be in PHP...

Comment: Do you programmatically generate this output?

Comment: this html is echoed via php? or you read this page in your script?

Comment: How are you generating this html in PHP ?? Your code ?

Comment: @phant0m: Don't know exactly what you meant but the raw code snippet above is generated by another script and I would like to filter it the way I explained above.

Comment: Well, if you already use a script to generate said HTML, why not adjust that or parameterize it? There's no point in generating too much and then use a DOM parser to remove it...

Comment: @phant0m: it's a third party script and it's hidden in a file somewhere I don't know..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml('<div id="category">
   <ul class="products">
     <li>{nested child elements}</li>
     <li>{nested child elements}</li>
     <li>{nested child elements}</li>
   </ul>
</div>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//li[position()>1]') as $liNode) {
    $liNode->parentNode->removeChild($liNode);
}

$output = '';
foreach ($xpath->query('//body/*') as $child) {
    $output .= $dom->saveXml($child);
}
```

Output:

```
<div id="category">
   <ul class="products">
     <li>{nested child elements}</li>


   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @jilseego It works in the example I've given. If it doesn't work for you, then you'll probably have malformed html to start with. Please provide more detailed information / examples of your data.

Comment: @Yhoshi: ul has siblings, would that affect the query?

Comment: @jilseego No. The xpath query `//li` just simply selects every li-node in the given document. With `[position()>1]` this is reduced to only those which are not the first child under their parent. Coud you update your question to include the html, for which this code doesn't work?

Comment: @Yoshi: I have updated my question. I don't have the code that generates the html code. But that's pretty much what it returns when I examined it using print_r.

Comment: @jilseego Try the updated code. I'll just take a guess and say that `$content` does not contain well-formed html (only one root node for example). The changed code uses `loadHtml` to accommodate for that.

Comment: @Yoshi: Still didn't work. If you don't mind you can take a look at my site: http://goo.gl/nKMEU . At the bottom where it says featured products, under ul.xoxo, that's the code get_code() generates.

Comment: @jilseego I copied the code from the site you've given (hopefully the correct chunk), and used that as input for the above code (ignoring the many `htmlParseEntityRef` warnings for now), and it stills produces the correct result (removing every li except the first under it's parent). Can you please define: *Still didn't work*

Comment: @Yoshi: Thanks, you've done enough. Your code works when tested with dummy html as shown in your example. There must be something with my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use DOMDocument.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$ul = $dom->getElementById('category')->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0);

foreach($ul->getElementsByTagName('li') as $index => $li) {
   if ($index == 0) {
      continue;
   }
   $ul->removeChild($li);
}
```