# PHP remove all div with class="myclass" except first one + add another div instead of others

Tags: php

I have a $content with

```
<div class="slidesWrap">
   <div class="slidesСontainer">
      <div class="myclass"> 
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="myclass">
        ...
      </div>
      ...
      ...
      <div class="myclass">
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="nav">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
some other text here, <p></p> bla-bla-bla
```

I would like to remove via PHP all the divs with class="myclass" except the first one, and add another div instead of others, so that the result is:

```
<div class="slidesWrap">
   <div class="slidesСontainer">
      <div class="myclass"> 
        ...
      </div>
      <div>Check all divs <a href="myurl">here</a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="nav">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
some other text here, <p></p> bla-bla-bla
```

Would be grateful if someone can point me a solution.

UDATE2:

some similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438035/remove-all-list-elements-except-the-first-in-php)
from that I came up with the following test code:

```
$content = '<div class="slidesWrap">
   <div class="slidesСontainer">
      <div class="myclass">
      </div>
      <div class="myclass">
      </div>
      <div class="myclass">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="nav">
  </div>
  </div>
 some other text here, <p></p> bla-bla-bla';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($content);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@class="myClass" and position()>1]') as $liNode) {
    $liNode->parentNode->removeChild($liNode); 
}

echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
```

Any ideas where I can test it?

Comment: are you open to doing this using jQuery as it might be a lot easier to achieve?

Comment: Investigate [DOM](http://php.net/dom) or other (X)HTML parsers of your choice.

Comment: unfortunately I need to do it with PHP, no jQuery.

Comment: you could do that by if-statements

Comment: Though I don't know why, the question calls for a PHP solution. This solution could also apply to other problems where JavaScript isn't an option.

Comment: Could be easily done using jquery selectors

Comment: I need to do is a part of WordPress add_filter function to filter post content from images before sending to e-mail (MailPress)/crosspost to LJ, that's why PHP-only.

Comment: Use DOMXpath to select and then DOMDocument to write the new div in.

Comment: @Blowski I found a similar question here (updated post), could you maybe help with the right query?

Comment: Does my answer not suite your needs? I believe it works fine, try it.

Comment: @manticore I replied below your answer

Comment: @Denis Where can you test it? Not sure what you mean. PHPUnit, any browser-based Xpath plugin, or your actual code. It does look right, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for (similar to your edit, but it removes the added html tags):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);

$xp = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xp->query("//div[@class='myclass']");

if($elements->length > 1)
{
    $newElem = $doc->createElement("div");
    $newElem->appendChild($doc->createTextNode("Check all divs "));
    $newElemLink = $newElem->appendChild($doc->createElement("a"));
    $newElemLink->setAttribute("href", "myurl");
    $newElemLink->appendChild($doc->createTextNode("here"));

    $elements->item(1)->parentNode->replaceChild($newElem, $elements->item(1));     

    for($i = $elements->length - 1; $i > 1 ; $i--)
    {
        $elements->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($elements->item($i));
    }
}

echo $doc->saveXML($doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know here I can check the code on-line? I try http://ideone.com but it seems not to process it?

Comment: You needed to add php tags (see http://ideone.com/QFrYb), but it doesn't look like ideaone supports DOMDocument. Where is this code to be run? Don't you have a development server or something?

Comment: thank you, it does work. p/s/ I have a server, but wanted to try it before applying it to my site.

Comment: funny enough, it does not 'like' some text after div's, like "some other text here, <p></p> bla-bla-bla"

Comment: that seems to do the trick 'echo $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);'

Answer (score -1):

```
$var = ':not(.myClass:eq(1))';   
$var.removeClass("myClass");
$var.addClass("some_other_Class");
```

Comment: wouldn't this only remove the class, and not the div itself

Comment: Yup, but he said, he need to remove a div and then add another. I think its equivalent to removing one and adding another to the same div in one selection

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, do you mean it like this $content(':not(.myClass:eq(1))).removeClass("myClass") ?

Comment: no, he said he needs to replace multiple divs with one div. So, if he initially had n divs, his final product needs to have 2 divs. One for the first div, and 1 for the remaining (n-1) divs

Comment: Whats $content, I think my code will work fine without any modification for the given snippet of code

Comment: @Denis: this is jquery. It won't serve your purpose

Comment: @PrashantSingh: Your new code is also adding/removing classes (CSS classes). He needs to add/remove the entire div itself (HTML element)

Comment: What language/library/what is this? It's certainly neither PHP nor jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

If I got you right, you've got a string called `$content` with all that content in it
It's not the best solution I guess but here is my attempt (which works fine for me):

```
if( substr_count($content, '<div class="myclass') > 1 ) {
    $parts = explode('<div class="myclass',$content);
    echo '<div class="myclass'.$parts[1];
    echo '<div>Check all divs <a href="myurl">here</a></div>';
}
else {echo $content;}
```

Comment: i'm not sure how explode function works, but from documentation it should split a string using delimiter. I guess that would work if applied to the string with div=myclass only, but not to general html structure I have?

Comment: It surely works but that's only half the code.
You have to search for the first closing </div> within that string to get only the div you want and not everthing until the next <div class="myclass'.

Comment: The only thing worse than [regexen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476) for "parsing" HTML is `substr`. Use an X(HT)ML parser!

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply and you're vote down. I really appreciate it! Makes me want to show more effort than I already did! *ironic off*

Comment: -1 @manticore The problem with regex or substr solutions is that they assume too much about the HTML in the $content string. For example, an inner div will produce an extra closing </div>. Sure you can get round that problem, but DOMDocument (and other parsers) already does the job. (Also -1 for sarcasm.  Points are awarded for correctness, not effort.)

Comment: Okay I understand now. No answering as long as I don't have my master in IT and wrote my doctoral thesis about it.

Comment: Then another guy quits SO.